# 3 Dice Sum Counting Program Java

Tags: java, arrays, sum, counting, dice

For my Computer Science Class, my teacher is asking us to do the following:

Program Description:  You are learning to play a new game that involves 3 six-sided die.  You know that if you knew the probability for each of the possible rolls of the die that you’d be a much better competitor.

Since you have just been studying arrays and using them to count multiple items that this program should be a snap to write.  This will be cool since the last time we did this we work just looking for how many times 9 or 10 could be rolled and this program won’t require any if statements.

Required Statements:  output, loop control, array

Sample Output:

Number   Possible Combinations

1                0

2                0

3                1

4                3

5                6

6               10

7               15

8               21

9               25

10               27

11               27

12               25

13               21

14               15

15               10

16                6

17                3

18                1

I can easily do this with an if statement, but I don't understand how to do it without one. It is especially tricky because under hints, she wrote: "These programs utilize a counting array. Each time a value is generated the position at that index is incremented. It’s like the reverse of the lookup table." I have no idea what this means.

Here's my code with the if statement:

```
public class prog410a
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Number\tPossible Combinations");

        for (int x = 1; x <= 18; x++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int k = 1; k <= 6; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i ++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
                    {
                        if (k + i + j == x)
                            count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(x + "\t\t\t" + count);
        }

    }
}
```

So I guess my overall question is this: How can I emulate this, but by using some sort of array instead of an if statement?

Comment: Do *you* count from one to 18 before you roll the die? Roll, add up, count...

Comment: 3 dices (6 face) so the sum go from 1 to max (6+6+6=18). Solution: Create an array of integer of 18 cells. Initaliasize all cell to 0. In the last loop, just do the following my_array[i+j+k] = my_array[i+j+k] + 1. That's all. (be sure to output your table at the end of the program).

Comment: To be fair, the directions even tell you to use an array.

Comment: @Alexx What's wrong with `my_array[i+j+k] += 1`

Comment: @Powerlord Or even `my_array[i+j+k]++;`?

Comment: @Alexxx If you use an integer array of 18 cells, you can't use `my_array[i+j+k]`.

Comment: @Alexxx An `int[]` does not need initialization to all 0.

Comment: @Alexxx min value is 3 for 3 dices (6 face) ... unless you manage to balance 2 of 3 dices on their corners.

Comment: @Powerlord: it just a general quick answer easly understandable (in my point of view). Sure you can use +=1 or ++. But as the question seems really simple, I've written an answer without += 1 or ++ (to advance? :p)

Comment: @Filburt Sure, but I didn't tell between min (=...)  ans max (6+6+6). I told between 1 and max (6+6+6). Sure you can manage the only max-min cell, so starting at 3. But cell 0 will manage the amount for 3, cell 1 the amount for 4... and so on, and you will to manage a shift, which is too complex regarding the benefit. And if you read the provided example, the output start at 1 not 3 (yes, you can also manage output).

Comment: @Alexxx sorry for nitpicking but I was referring to *"sum go from 1 to max ...18"* - not the array index. I'd have guessed the teacher could have awarded a bonus if students figured out that the min sum would be 3 and optimized the array but then the sample output already shows 0 for sum=1 and sum=2. Purely academic but important to gently steer the young ones to wrap their head around this kind of shifting - it will likely spare them some headache when they are introduced to pointers later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the outer x loop. All you need is three nested loops, one for each die. You will also need an array of integers all initialized to zero. Inside the innermost dice loop, you just use the sum of the three dice as the index to you integer array and increment the value at that index.

After you complete the dice loops, then you can iterate over your integer array and output the frequency of your results.

Comment: So something like:
count[i+j+k] += 1;
?
My only question is how that specifically counts when the die add up to the specific number.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I figured it out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I won't write the code for you, just give you the general outline.

Create a count array of size 18.  Initialise all values to 0.

Have three nested loops counting from 1 to 6 exactly like your three inner loops.  These represent the values on your dice.

Inside your innermost loop, add the three loop counters together.  This is your dice total and you use it as an index into the count array to increment the value at that index.

After you exit the three nested loops, use another loop to iterate through the count array to print out the values.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work - and without `if`:

```
public void test() {
    // Remember to -1 because arrays are accessed from 0 to length-1
    int[] counts = new int[18];
    // Dice 1.
    for (int k = 1; k <= 6; k++) {
        // Dice 2.
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            // Dice 3.
            for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
                // Count their sum (-1 as noted above).
                counts[i + j + k - 1] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // Print out the array.
    System.out.println("Number\tPossible Combinations");
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + (i + 1) + "\t" + counts[i]);
    }
}
```

Essentially you build the results in an array then output them.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia: [In computer science, a lookup table is an array that replaces runtime computation with a simpler array indexing operation. The savings in terms of processing time can be significant, since retrieving a value from memory is often faster than undergoing an 'expensive' computation or input/output operation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table), this means that usually we use lookup tables to save computation time by precalculating some process into a table in which we already stored the result. In this case you are using the process to store the number of possible outcomes in an array. Basically you are building a lookup table for the dice outcome. Only the three inner loops are needed.

```
        for (int k = 1; k <= 6; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i ++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
                {
                    arr[k + i + j-1] = arr[k + i + j-1] +1;
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is what is happening:

```
dices   index
i j k  (i+j+k)
1 1 1     3
1 1 2     4
1 1 3     5
1 1 4     6
1 1 5     7
1 1 6     8
1 2 1     4
1 2 2     5
1 2 3     6
1 2 4     7
1 2 5     8
1 2 6     9
1 3 1     5
1 3 2     6
.
.
.
```

You are enumerating each possible outcome and then adding the spot in the array with the index generated. When the nested loops are done, you will have an array containing the desired information.